# How to make certain endpoint in spring security to be allowed without authentication?

Tags: spring-security

I'm developing an application using Spring security.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/client/findByVariable?variable=").permitAll();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**")
                .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('USER'))");
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

How can I modify above code so that endpoint "/api/client/findByVariable?variable=" can be allowed to be accessed without requiring authentication just as if there was no Spring Security ?
I tried adding the line :

```
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/client/findByVariable?variable=").permitAll();
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore endpoints with overriding the configure method that gives you a `WebSecurity` instance:

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web)
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/client/findByVariable");
    }
```

I'm not sure if you can also match by query params like `/api/client/findByVariable?variable=*`